# How can I show a registration form that also display a list of cities and gender a user can choose?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model, controller

This is my current model. The class is named exactly as my database table and I intend to use Entity Framework to get the information.

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastNameFather { get; set; }
    public string LastNameMother { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int Telephone { get; set; }
    public int MobilePhone { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfRegistry { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastDateLogin { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public int LanceCreditBalance { get; set; }
    public int LancesSpent { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Nickname { get; set; }
    public string EmailVerificationCode { get; set; }

    public int GenderId { get; set; }
    public virtual Gender Gender { get; set; }

    public int CityId { get; set; }
    public virtual City City { get; set; }
}
```

How would my controllers look like?

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Register()
{
    //How do I load the Cities and Genders here as dropdownlists? Remember
    //they are foreign key values.    

    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register()
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //Actually save the user here.
        RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }            

    //Something went wrong, redisplay the form for correction.
    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not really a wise choice to use the Database model in the View. You should use a **ViewModel**. In the ViewModel you should have the properties you need to fill in the view.

So in your case you would probably need all the properties from the User Model and 2 SelectLists for your Cities and Genders.

So you should have this:

**View Model**

```
    public class InsertUserViewModel
    {

        ///All the properties for your User
        ///The 2 SelectLists
        ///2 properties for the selectedValues from thoses list.

        public List<SelectListItem> Cities{ get; set; }
        public int/string or whatever SelectedCity { get; set; } 


    }
```

**Get**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
         InsertUserViewModel oNewUserViewModel = new InsertUserViewModel();
        //Fill in the SelectLists values with the values from your database
         List<SelectListItem> Cities= new List<SelectListItem>();
         Cities.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "New York", Value = "0", Selected = true});      
         Cities.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Paris", Value = "1", Selected = false});

        return View();
    }
```

**Post**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(InsertUserViewModel oPostedUserViewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //Make a new User object with the properties from the ViewModel ant save it.


        RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }            

    //Something went wrong, redisplay the form for correction.
    return View(model);
}
```

**Your View**

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedCity , Model.Cities)
```

Comment: Thanks but in the past I've had two SelectLists in my ViewModel and when running the application I recieved an exception that it doesn't have a parameterless constructor. Any other ideas?

Comment: You must have done something wrong then. I updated my code with the correct use of the SelectLists